# Declaring ArrayLists: difference in Functionality?

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I'm curious, When declaring ArrayLists, What is the difference in doing this:

```
List<String> arrayList1= new ArrayList<String>();
```

and this:

```
List<String> arrayList2= new ArrayList<>();
```

i.e. not declaring the `<String>` twice?

Comment: There's no difference, the second one is equal to the first one, but it is only possible after Java 7.

Comment: Second one is just a code-sugar (it is called diamond notation)

Answer (score 1):

the only difference is that the first form is compatible with earlier java versions than java 7.

Answer (score -2):

And you don't need the <> either in latter versions. e.g

```
List<String> arrayList2= new ArrayList();
```

Comment: This is *not* the same thing. Here, you're assigning a raw type to a generic variable, and so do *not* get the type safety generics provides.

Comment: For more information about raw types, see [this section](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ParameterizedTypes.html#Raw) of the excellent GenericsFAQ.